# Minimalize event handler

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to add a handler to the form button for the form minimalization? My application doesn't use windows frame and I would like to handle window event inside of my code.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub btnMin_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
      Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh, thats not my point. I want to minimalize the window myself, using any function.

Comment: oh sorry.i have reedited my answer and added the correct code.

Comment: Thank you! Thats what I wanted!